# What is the print result of an object?

Tags: ios, swift

Printing the `tableView` object:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(tableView)
}
```

Results in `<UITableView: 0x7fe33701e000...`

Is `0x7fe33701e000` the memory address of the object `tableView` or is it the ID or what is it? Help is very appreciated.

**Addition**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {        
    withUnsafePointer(to: &tableView) {
        print("\(tableView) has address: \($0)")
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
<UITableView: 0x7fcdca810600... has address: 0x00007fff594533f0
```

So I'm able to exclude the idea that it might be the memory address(?).

Comment: Also see https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418799-description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x7fcdca810600` is the address of the `UITableView` instance pointed to by the `tableView` variable.

`0x00007fff594533f0` is the address of the `tableView` variable.

Your original thought was correct.

BTW - the output of printing classes, such as `UITableView` is from the `description` method. The default is to show the object's type and memory address. You can change the output by implementing or overriding the `description` method.

Comment: So `0x7fcdca810600` is the memory adress of the `UITableView` instance and `0x00007fff594533f0` is the adress of the object `tableView` ?

Comment: No. It's what I said in my answer. `tableView` is not an object. It's a variable. The variable (the pointer) is in memory at one address and it points to the actual object (the `UITableView` instance).

Comment: Ah okay. Yes, my bad.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: @DavidSeek Referring to implementing `description` method In Swift, you should check [CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible) protocol.